# Is there any way I could get a resolution of 1200*700 in the FIFA 16 Demo configuration settings?

Tags: fifa-16

My pc lags when I play FIFA 16/FIFA 15 due to the high screen resolution, so I want to set it lower, like I did for FIFA 14. Is this possible, for example by command prompt or download specific files.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is possible, but i'd like to point out that your specs probably are not up to date.